# Things i need to know to build a real time feed system in Django

Tags: django

I want to build a simple app where i have different users and they make updates and all the users get the updates in real time much like facebook.

**Edit:**
I just want to know how to push updates to profiles of users without them reloading the page. Do i make repeated AJAX calls or is there something out there that can solve this problem for me.

**Edit 2:**
Here's a presentation which helped me http://www.slideshare.net/oellegaard/implementing-real-time-web-applications-with-django

Comment: You might want to do some initial investigation and come back with a more specific question if you have one - this is way too general

Comment: This is way too general. What have you tried? What specific problems/hurdles did you encounter?

Comment: @Chris  i googled it and got confused on how to push updates to profiles of the users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for real-time like interaction, one idea is to use sockets.

What I would do is write my front facing site in python/django, and have a node.js layer behind that w/ socket.io (websockets) that handles keeping all of the clients in sync.

```
               [DB]
               /  \
        [Django]  [node.js]
app logic -> \      / <- async updates
             [Browser]
```

but really this is a fairly uninformed answer based heavily on assumptions b/c you haven't told us anything concrete about what your site needs to do.

Comment: So basically i design my app in django, save messages in DB, make node.js layer fetch updates and send that to every profile by polling it time to time.. did i get it right?

Comment: something like that. it depends on the exact sort of user interaction you are trying to build. What you just described works for general async updates, but would not work for a realtime p2p chat. for p2p chat all chat messages would go through the socket connection (else there would be noticable delays) it really just depends on the precise "what" you are trying to accomplish

Comment: ascii drawings always deserve an upvote

Answer (score -2):

You need to know how to Program, you need to know Python, and the Django Framework, you will need to know HTML, JavaScript, and CSS, you will need to know some Database of your choice, you will need to know enough to make educated decisions about MVC frameworks on the Client Side, you will need to know about Queues, Stacks, Asynchronous Callbacks, HTTP methods, Encryption and other Security Practices, the list goes on.

Basically, you need to know more then someone who would ask the question you asked.